# Bootstrap A Link in html is not clickable

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have an issue with Bootstrap 3.2.0, Link is unable to be click.

Below is parts of my code (generated from php):

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-7"  style="padding-left: 50px; padding-top: 10px;">
        <div class="big_dialog_title_grey" style="height: 50px; max-width: 770px;">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-8">
                    <h4 style="font-weight: bold; padding-left: 20px;">Manage My Listings</h4>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-4" style="padding-top: 10px;">
                    <img style="-webkit-border-radius: 3px; -moz-border-radius: 3px; border-radius: 3px; padding: 5px; border: 1px #d3d3d3 solid; background: #f6f6f6; min-height: 28px;" src="/assets/images/template/user/dashboard/icon/manage_icon1.png">&nbsp;
                    <span style="border-left: 2px #d3d3d3 solid; height: 23px; display: inline-block;">&nbsp;</span>&nbsp;
                    <img style="-webkit-border-radius: 3px; -moz-border-radius: 3px; border-radius: 3px; padding: 5px; border: 1px #d3d3d3 solid; background: #f6f6f6; min-height: 28px;" src="/assets/images/template/user/dashboard/icon/manage_icon2.png">&nbsp;
                    <img style="-webkit-border-radius: 3px; -moz-border-radius: 3px; border-radius: 3px; padding: 5px; border: 1px #d3d3d3 solid; background: #f6f6f6; min-height: 28px;" src="/assets/images/template/user/dashboard/icon/manage_icon3.png">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="scrollable" style="position: relative; margin-left: 1px; height: 580px; width: 769px; background: #f5f5f5;">
                                <div class="row" style="max-width: 779px; padding: 10px; border-bottom: 1px #D8D8D8 solid; background: #F7F7F7;">
                    <div class="col-md-1" style="vertical-align: middle;">
                                                    <img src="/assets/images/template/user/dashboard/icon/approved_icon.png" style="padding-left: 10px; padding-top: 40px;">
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-3">
                        <img src="/assets/uploader/upload/2014719123490_8ccd6329-2bfd-48cc-bcee-4b3136dc3adf/1.JPG" style="height: 108px; width: 167px;">
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-6" style="margin-top: 25px; vertical-align: middle; font-weight: bold;">
                        Pluit, Jakarta Utara, 14450                            <div style="font-weight: normal;">yyyyy</div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-2">
                        <a class="edit_yellow_button" style="vertical-align;text-align: center; font-weight:bold; margin-top: 25px; padding-top: 5px;" href="/user/edit_property?id=2014719123490">Edit</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
                                <div class="row" style="max-width: 779px; padding: 10px; border-top: 2px white solid; border-bottom: 2px white solid; background: #EFEFEF;">
                    <div class="col-md-1" style="vertical-align: middle;">
                                                    <img src="/assets/images/template/user/dashboard/icon/approved_icon.png" style="padding-left: 10px; padding-top: 40px;">
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-3">
                        <img src="/assets/uploader/upload/2014714134610_2ef67d2d-de84-4782-8e46-09452c4db783/2.JPG" style="height: 108px; width: 167px;">
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-6" style="margin-top: 25px; vertical-align: middle; font-weight: bold;">
                        Pluit, Jakarta Utara, 14450                            <div style="font-weight: normal;">bcvbcvbvc</div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-2">
                        <a class="edit_yellow_button" style="vertical-align;text-align: center; font-weight:bold; margin-top: 25px; padding-top: 5px;" href="/user/edit_property?id=2014714134610">Edit</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
                                <div class="row" style="max-width: 779px; padding: 10px; border-top: 1px #D8D8D8 solid; border-bottom: 1px #D8D8D8 solid; background: #F7F7F7;">
                    <div class="col-md-1" style="vertical-align: middle;">
                                                    <img src="/assets/images/template/user/dashboard/icon/approved_icon.png" style="padding-left: 10px; padding-top: 40px;">
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-3">
                        <img src="/assets/uploader/upload/201478142490_5a4b8bb5-0d5a-469b-b488-dcc8a7d4ae4e/Rmh Grand Prima Bintara,lt.193,lb.260,kt.4+1,km.3+1,hrga 2,3 M.jpg" style="height: 108px; width: 167px;">
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-6" style="margin-top: 25px; vertical-align: middle; font-weight: bold;">
                        Pluit, Jakarta Utara, 14450                            <div style="font-weight: normal;">XXXXXXXX</div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-2">
                        <a class="edit_yellow_button" style="vertical-align;text-align: center; font-weight:bold; margin-top: 25px; padding-top: 5px;" href="/user/edit_property?id=201478142490">Edit</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
                                <div class="row" style="max-width: 779px; padding: 10px; border-top: 2px white solid; background: #EFEFEF;">
                    <div class="col-md-1" style="vertical-align: middle;">
                                                    <img src="/assets/images/template/user/dashboard/icon/approved_icon.png" style="padding-left: 10px; padding-top: 40px;">
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-3">
                        <img src="/assets/uploader/upload/2014781334560_ba49ee0d-332e-4b7b-aa62-4c5858d42565/Rmh Grand Prima Bintara,lt.193,lb.260,kt.4+1,km.3+1,hrga 2,3 M.jpg" style="height: 108px; width: 167px;">
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-6" style="margin-top: 25px; vertical-align: middle; font-weight: bold;">
                        Pluit, Jakarta Utara, 14450                            <div style="font-weight: normal;">ytytytytytytytytyt</div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-2">
                        <a class="edit_yellow_button" style="vertical-align;text-align: center; font-weight:bold; margin-top: 25px; padding-top: 5px;" href="/user/edit_property?id=2014781334560">Edit</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
                            <div style="position:absolute; bottom:0; height: 64px; vertical-align: middle; text-align: center; width: 765px;">
                    <span style="margin-top: 20px; text-align: center; display: inline-block;">
                        Page Number
                    </span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-5" style="padding-left: 175px; padding-top: 10px;">
        <img src="/assets/images/template/user/dashboard/mockup/upgrade_premium.png">
    </div>
</div>
```

Also when attaching onclick code into **edit_yellow_button** is not working.

Thank you guys for helping :)

[Fiddle for the same](http://jsfiddle.net/Q7fww/)

Comment: How is it not working?

Comment: @AnthonyChu  It wont able to click that EDIT link, when you click is nothing happen

Comment: the code is working all right @Frank added a jsfiddle. Which Edit is giving the hard time?

Answer (score 0):

I just found that code is not working at my end but working using jsfiddle, because of overlapping `div` that caused the issue and now its fixed, by changing `col-md-7` to `col-md-9` and `col-md-5` to `col-md-3`